# Unable to Change Database Default Collate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I cannot alter database tempdb because it is a system database.

I installed a fresh SQL Server 2008 R2 on my system, by default it got the collation as `Latin1_General_C1_Ai_WS`. But my Database Collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_C1_Ai_AS`.

So, I am getting Collation Error in all the places whereever I have used temp tables.

All temp (#) tables are getting created with the default collate `Latin1_General_C1_Ai_WS`, so wherever I have used temp table, I am getting an error.

I tried reconfiguring but it didn't work.

Because of this I am manually adding collate in all temp tables.

Please Help.... Thank You!

Comment: What is so difficult about adding `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` to comparison operations involving temp tables?  It is completely normal to do in a mixed collation environment.  If you don't like typing it, then you either have to rebuild the system dbs or worse yet, removing data out and drop/add char and text columns in your user db, or script things using export wizard ect.

Comment: I can't change my DB Collate as it has to be similar to Production, i have to change the Collate of the  Master Database which i am not able to do in my local environment. (Master Database / Temp Db sets the collate of the temp tables). so I need to update the Collate in the Master DB and Temp Db. Otherwise i can't change the temp tables used inside 2000 + SP's which error out.

Comment: So the answer is your current instance isn't configured the same as your production.  There is no work around.  Rebuild your non-prod system dbs to match your desired collation OR change your #temp table calls.

Comment: Could Please help me out in the following command for Rebuilding. i am getting  the Exception "Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException"     Syntax : Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=system-02 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=sa [ /SAPWD= $Temp123 ] [ /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin_General_CP1_Ci_AS]

My command : Setup.exe /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=system-02 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=administrator /SAPWD= Temp123 /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

You either do what you say you are doing, forcing the temp tables to have the same collation as your database, or you change the default collation of the database.  But this latter is complicated and takes quite a bit of work.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx) for a step by step.

I'd go ahead and change the default collation and actual collation of your database, using those steps, if I were you.  More work now, but will save you tons of headaches later.

Comment: while Changing the Server Collation - rebuilding , i am getting generic error - find the details in the Summary.txt.                               Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException
Message: The state of your SQL Server installation was not changed after the setup execution. Please review the summary.txt logs for further details. Please let me know how resolve this issue. It is my local environment, so i have all the access still unable.  One more thing, why i am not able to  directly modifty in Database-->Master-->Properties--> Options-->Collation